# add multiple tags to form in net core 3.1 mvc

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-core-mvc

In my project users can add a entry in the database of a video they want to store. The video is supposed to have multiple tags (optional) go with it. What is a good way to let users enter dynamically multiple tags?

I have created three models, Video, Tag and VideoTags, which holds the m2m relationship of the tags for each video.

Video

```
public class Video: BaseModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string OriginUrl { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string FileLocationIcon { get; set; }
    public ICollection<VideoTags> VideoTags { get; set; }
}
```

Tag

```
public class Tag: BaseModel
{        
    public string TagName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<VideoTags> VideoTags { get; set; }
}
```

VideoTags

```
public class VideoTags
{
    public string VideoId { get; set; }
    public Video Video { get; set; }

    public string TagId { get; set; }
    public Tag Tag { get; set; }

}
```

My html (Create.cshtml)

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <form asp-action="Create" enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post">
        <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Name" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="Name" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Name" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="OriginalUrl" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="OriginalUrl" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="OriginalUrl" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Description" class="control-label"></label>
            <textarea asp-for="Description" class="form-control"> </textarea>
            <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="Icon" class="control-label"></label>
            <input type="file" asp-for="Icon" class="form-control" accept="image/x-png,image/gif,image/jpeg" />
            <span asp-validation-for="Icon" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
        </div>
    </form>
</div>
```

Now, my question is how can I properly implement this on my html form where the user provides the other details of the Video entry?
I think it will involve `JQuery`, but I don't really know how to proceed. Users are supposed to add these tags, so I want them to be able to add input fields if needed, and then on Submit to the backend, my `Controller` will take that input and turn it into a `IEnumerable` or `List`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> This is part of the code I used in my online store project.

---

### ***Solution:***

We should have two inputs.

1. The first input is only a display and is what the user is working
   on.
2. The second input is exactly what holds the entered tags and
   ultimately allows us to send them all to the server.

### ***Operation:***

The user enters a value in the first input. You can then enter your keyword by hitting the `+` key or the `Enter key`.
According to the rules of Google or Bing or any other search engine, keywords must be separated by `,`.
So what we do is paste a comma into the end of a keyword after entering it. Also, this process continues until the end.

### ***Emphasis:***

Of course, this is not the only way we can get keywords from the user. But I think it's one of the best methods that is still popular. Unlike the `ICollection` definition method, this method does not need to create a `for loop` to print the tags, and all the tags are printed together and search engines can follow them. So this method works much faster than the `ICollection` method.
Also, your user will be much more comfortable with this method and will have a more enjoyable user experience.

### ***Footnote:***

Finally, if you have more questions about this method or my code, ask me. I will try to answer them as soon as possible.
I hope this answer meets all your needs. I invite you to accept this answer if this is the case.

---

```js
//call addKey() by pressing Enter (  This block is optional!  )
$(window).keydown(function(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 13) {
    event.preventDefault();
    addKey();
    return false;
  }
});

//call addKey() by pressing button
$('#addKey').click(function(e) {
  addKey();
});


//Add key function
function addKey() {
  let key = $('#keysInput').val()
  if (key != '') {
    let tag = document.createElement('span')
    $(tag).append(key)
    $(tag).attr('onclick', `$(this).remove();removeKey("${key}");`)
    $('.addedKeysHolder').append(tag)
    $('#keysInput').val('')
    resetKey()
  }
}

//According to my goals, this function was equal to the resetKey(). But here I put it in a separate block, so you can easily customize it if you want
function removeKey() {
  resetKey()
}

//Reset all keys
function resetKey() {
  $('#lkey').val('')
  for (let i = 1; i <= $('.addedKeysHolder span').length; i++) {
    let theKey = $(`.addedKeysHolder span:nth-child(${i})`).text()
    let prevVal = $('#lkey').val() + ','
    $('#lkey').val(prevVal + theKey)
  }
  $('#lkey').val($('#lkey').val());
  $('#keysInput').focus();
}
```

```css
/*  Just add some styles to make it beautiful  */
*,
::after,
::before {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.keyHandler {
  float: left;
  width: 250px;
  height: 40px;
}

.keyHandler>button {
  float: left;
  height: 100%;
  width: 40px;
  border: none;
  outline: none !important;
  background: #673AB7;
  border-radius: 7px;
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  font-size: 26pt;
}

.keyHandler>input {
  float: left;
  width: calc(100% - 45px);
  margin: 0 0 0 5px;
  height: 38px;
  padding: 0 14px;
  background: #ffffff;
  border: none;
  outline: none !important;
  font-family: monospace;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #673AB7;
}

.addedKeysHolder {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  margin: 8px 0 0 0;
}

.addedKeysHolder>span {
  background: #2196F3;
  padding: 8px 10px 8px 30px;
  float: left;
  margin: 2px;
  border-radius: 100px;
  color: white;
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size: 12pt;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.addedKeysHolder>span:after {
  content: "\d7";
  position: absolute;
  left: 12px;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 14px;
  height: 14px;
  line-height: .5;
  margin: auto;
  font-size: 17pt;
}
```

```html
<div class="keyHandler">
  <button type="button" id="addKey">+</button>
  <input type="text" placeholder="Keyword + Enter" id="keysInput">
</div>
<div class="addedKeysHolder"></div>


<!-- Just give this input the name="etc" attribute -->
<input type="hidden" id="lkey" name="tags">


<!--------------------------------------------------->
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: thank you very much for your time. I'll test this asap!

Comment: I've looking for this a lot. thanks a lot. but I also thinking about put a suggestion list from database.

Comment: @sudhananda-biswas , so this was the day of days for you. you will need to use `ajax` to implement the thing you want. when user types in input, send the text via ajax and get the similar result. [Take a look at here](https://www.google.com/search?q=ajax+real+time+search&oq=ajax+realtime+sea&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0i22i30.8290j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Answer (score 1):

It does not need `ICollection` to add tags. You can use only one `string` and use jQuery to implement. see the example:

```js
let myArray = [];
$(document).on('click', '#makeTags', function(){
    if ($('#givTags').val()){
    let prev = $('#sendTags').val(),
          typed = $('#givTags').val(),
        make = prev + ',' + typed;
        $('#sendTags').val(make);
    $('#givTags').val('');
  }
});
```

```css
#givTags, #sendTags {
    width: 400px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 0 20px;
  outline: none !important;
}
#makeTags {
    border: none;
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 9px;
    background: #e4e4e4;
    margin: 10px 0 0 0;
    color: dimgrey;
    cursor: pointer;
    outline: none !important;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="givTags" value="" placeholder="write any thing and then press button..." />
<br />
<button id="makeTags">send tags</button>
<br />
<br />
<br />
<input type="text" name="tags" id="sendTags" value="" placeholder="make it's type as hidden after you find out how it works" />

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js" integrity="sha256-QWo7LDvxbWT2tbbQ97B53yJnYU3WhH/C8ycbRAkjPDc=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

your class:

```
public class Video: BaseModel
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string OriginUrl { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string FileLocationIcon { get; set; }
    public string VideoTags { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @CMorgan Great! If your issue is resolved then I invite you to accept my answer, and if it was helpful then please also remember to upvote it as well, Cheers

Comment: This worked, but what should be added to have the user edit the tags and removing them?

Comment: I did this once in my own project. Allow me a few minutes to share the codes I used with you in another reply.