# ASP.NET Core creating custom input tag helper

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a form that has multiple fields, that each can take multiple inputs (based on this question [add multiple tags to form in net core 3.1 mvc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65634833/add-multiple-tags-to-form-in-net-core-3-1-mvc))

Currently it looks like this

```
<input type="text" class="multiple-input form-control text-right" id="teams-input" container-name="teams-container">
                <div class="row justify-content-end" input-name="teams-hidden">
                    <div id="teams-container" class="col-md-12 multiple-input-container"></div>
                </div>
                <input asp-for="Teams" type="hidden" id="teams-hidden" />
```

Problem is, I use similar things multiple times across multiple forms, so I want to make custom tag helper for it.

Currently this tag helper looks like this

```
[HtmlTargetElement("input", Attributes = "[type = multi-input]")]
public class MultipleInputsTagHelper : TagHelper
{
    public ModelExpression For { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override async Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
    {
        output.Content.SetHtmlContent(@$"<input type='text' class='multiple-input form-control text-right' id='teams-input' container-name='{Name}-container'>
            <div class='row justify-content-end' input-name='{Name}-hidden'>
                <div id='{Name}-container' class='col-md-12 multiple-input-container'></div>
            </div>
            <input asp-for='{For}' type='hidden' id='{Name}-hidden' />");
    }
}
```

And used in form like this

```
<input multi-input asp-for="Teams" asp-name="teams"/>
```

But my tag helper is not applying for some reason. What could be the problem, and how to correctly make custom input tag helpers?

Comment: have you registered your taghelper?

Comment: @DanielA.White yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't specify the attribute names mapped with the corresponding properties, like this:

```
[HtmlTargetElement("input", Attributes = "multi-input")]
public class MultipleInputsTagHelper : TagHelper
{
  [HtmlAttributeName("asp-for")]
  public ModelExpression For { get; set; }
  [HtmlAttributeName("asp-name")]
  public string Name { get; set; }

  public override async Task ProcessAsync(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
  {
    output.Content.SetHtmlContent(@$"<input type='text' class='multiple-input form-control text-right' id='teams-input' container-name='{Name}-container'>
        <div class='row justify-content-end' input-name='{Name}-hidden'>
            <div id='{Name}-container' class='col-md-12 multiple-input-container'></div>
        </div>
        <input asp-for='{For}' type='hidden' id='{Name}-hidden' />");
  }
}
```

We use the `HtmlAttributeNameAttribute` to specify the mapped attribute used in the original razor code.